# Find matrix for given eigenvectors and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Find a matrix A to the eigenvalues 4 and -6 and the eigenvectors
>
> $ v_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix} $
>
> $ v_2 = \begin{pmatrix} -3 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

So I am solving:

$ \left( \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} - 4 \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \right) \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $

yielding in $a+3b= 4$ and $c+3d=12$

and the same for the other eigenvalue and eigenvector

$ \left( \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} + 6 \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \right) \cdot \begin{pmatrix} -3 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $

yielding in $ -3a+b = 18$ and $-3c+d=-6$.

The solution of this system is $a=-5$, $b=3$, $c=9$ and $d=3$.

But the matrix

$\begin{pmatrix} -5 & 3 \\ 9 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$

does not have the eigenvalues 4 and $-6\ldots$ Am I wrong? Where is my mistake?

Comment: Check your $c$. It should be $c = 3$.

Comment: Try diagonalization. $\begin{bmatrix}\vec{v_{1}} & \vec{v_{2}}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \lambda_{1} & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_{2}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\vec{v_{1}} & \vec{v_{2}}\end{bmatrix}^{-1}$ will have the desired eigenvectors and eigenvalues.

Comment: thank you!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $v_1$ and $v_2$ are orthogonal, the matrix can be written down directly:
$$ \lambda_1v_1 v_1'/|v_1|^2+ \lambda_2 v_2 v_2'/|v_2|^2 $$.

Applying the above to $v_i$ to see it is generally true.